# Related topics to topology question for elementary students

Tags: general-topology

A friend who is studying to become a teacher just sent me the following question from their student exercise group, looking for help:
[image: Elementary Topology Q]

Now, I know absolutely nothing about topology, but I did come up with a solution that meets all the requirements (assuming the roads need not be straight - it is not totally clear to me - from the question and the simpler example provided - whether this is permitted); however, **I am curious to know what topics in topology this question is related to? or how one would describe the topological issues at hand in simple terms?**

I quickly got the sense that there are some general principles involved - perhaps related to the dimension of the space and the equivalence of shapes - and am now curious to explore the concepts related to this question.

Comment: Looks like questions about planar graphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it’s leading up to a [classic result, due to Kuratowski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#Kuratowski.27s_and_Wagner.27s_theorems), about [planar graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph). This theorem implies that if you start with five or more points in the plane and draw lines connecting every pair of them, at least two of the lines *must* cross each other. Thus, the task would be impossible if there were more than four children.

It also implies that if you start with two sets of three points each and draw lines from point of one set to each point of the other, at least two of the lines will necessarily intersect. It would not surprise me if the material included an exercise about this situation, too.

This material lies in the intersection of geometric topology and graph theory.

Comment: Indeed - there is a follow up question about 5 children. Strangely it says it's not possible in 2D, but then assigns exactly that problem (without any clear pedagogical guidance...). Are these results somehow tied to the dimensionality of the space (i.e. in a generalizable way)? i.e. is there anything more than the problem-solving experience that students might take away from it? Thank you kindly for the clear, direct answer and links!

Comment: @RaxAdaam: I suppose that the idea is simply to have the kids experiment with the case of $5$ children to get some sort of minimal feel for the problem, but I don’t really see the point: the theory involved is hard, so there’s nothing here that they can really discover. I’m not much impressed by these notes. Any finite graph can be embedded in $3$-space without crossings, and only a *very* limited class can be embedded in the line without crossings, so the plane is the only really interesting case, quite apart from the fact that it’s a practically useful case, but there’s no generalization ...

Comment: ... here that students at this level could discover. You’re welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I admit I'm not answering your question, exactly, but please don't have a curricular fit. Have your students each make a Mobius strip. Ask them how many sides and how many edges it has. Now have them cut their strip all the way around through the middle so that their Mobius strip is now two strips. Ask your students if these two strips are Mobius strips. Do NOT tell them to count the number of edges or the number of sides: somebody will think of that. This not really mathematics, but it **is** speculating and confirming something about geometry. And it's fun. This leads naturally to a discussion of identifying edges: making the side of a tin can by identifying two opposite edges of a rectangle, which is pretty much how tin cans are made, and then making the surface of a donut (torus) by identifying the two circles you have formed from the first identification.